# TFS build takes longer than same msbuild in command line

Tags: .net, wpf, msbuild

I've a performance issue with TFS 2013. I've a build definition (based on the process TfvcTemplate.12.xaml), it builds 3 solutions (with about 30 projects each, it's a WPF/WCF application). The build takes about 45minutes, since it seemed a lot of time (same build on our workstation takes few minutes) I've set the log level to diagnostic and found that when the msbuild compile the WPF projects it spends most of the time in the MarkupCompilePass1 and MarkupCompilePass2 tasks, here an example:

```
 1540 ms  GenerateTemporaryTargetAssembly            1 calls
 6353 ms  CoreCompile                                6 calls
 6840 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   5 calls
94682 ms  MarkupCompilePass1                         1 calls
112988 ms  MarkupCompilePass2                         1 calls
```

I've tried to execute the same msbuild statement in the command line on the same machine (same parameters, just changed the logfile paths) and it strangely took a lot less. The performance log for the same project:

```
 865 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   5 calls
 1493 ms  MarkupCompilePass2                         1 calls
 1730 ms  GenerateTemporaryTargetAssembly            1 calls
 1976 ms  MarkupCompilePass1                         1 calls
 7258 ms  Csc                                        6 calls
11879 ms  MSBuild                                   12 calls
```

Is there a reason behind this different behavior of the tfs build agent?

I've also tried to let the agent build a simple empty project and placed the msbuild commands inside a batch to execute after the build, but the outcome are the same, the tfs agent hangs and spend time in the MarkupCompilePass1/2.

Any help could be appreciated!

Comment: I've found that if I add the flag /p:AlwaysCompileMarkupFilesInSeparateDomain="False", it will cause the MarkupCompilePass2 to a reasonable duration (about 1s), the MarkupCompilePass1 still high...

Is it normal? (that parameter is set to True in the msbuild run manually via command line)

Another thing I was thinking about, could it be related to the user permission? (the user logged is the same that is set in the Build Controller, the only difference is that the command prompt is run with admin priviledge, the user is a domain user with local admin rights)

:(

Comment: I've also test the execution of msbuild inside TFS with elevated priviledge (using psexec and a powershell script) but it didn't solve the issue...